# How to remove black canvas from image in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow-datasets, tf.keras

I'm currenly trying working with tensorflow dataset 'tf_flowers', and noticed that a lot of images consist mostly of black canvas, like this:
[flower1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/drIPr.png)
[flower2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yf3ht.png)
Is there any easy way to remove/or filter it out? Preferably it should work on batches, and compile into a graph with @tf.function, as I plan to use it also for bigger datasets with dataset.map(...)

Comment: you can calculate the proportion of black pixels and then remove images above a certain threshold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The black pixels are just because of padding. This is a simple operation that allows you to have network inputs having the same size (i.e. you have batches containing images with the of size: 223x221 because smaller images are padded with black pixels).

**An alternative to padding** that removes the need of adding black pixels to the image, is that of preprocessing the images by:

- removing padding via cropping operation
- resizing the cropped images to the same size (e.g. 223x221)

You can do all of these operations in simple python, thanks to tensorflow map function. First, define your python function

```
def py_preprocess_image(numpy_image):
    input_size = numpy_image.shape  # this is (223, 221) 
    image_proc = crop_by_removing_padding(numpy_image)
    image_proc = resize(image_proc, size=input_size)
    return image_proc
```

Then, given your tensorflow dataset `train_data`, map the above python function on each input:

```
# train_data is your tensorflow dataset
train_data = train_data.map(
                 lambda x: tf.py_func(preprocess_image,
                                      inp = [x], Tout=[tf.float32]),
                 num_parallel_calls=num_threads
             )
```

Now, you only need to define `crop_by_removing_padding` and `resize`, which operate on ordinary numpy arrays and can thus be written in pure python code. For example:

```
def crop_by_removing_padding(img):
    xmax, ymax = np.max(np.argwhere(img), axis=0)
    img_crop = img[:xmax + 1, :ymax + 1]
    return img_crop

def resize(img, new_size):
    img_rs = cv2.resize(img, (new_size[1], new_size[0]), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
    return img_rs
```

Comment: I have a resize bult in my input pipeline (with biliniear interpolation). 
Even though the images before resizing still mostly have black canvas. 
Moreover I've also talked with my project supervisor about this, and we came to conclusion that the gradient over this black part will be always zeros, so there's no real need to wory about this.

Comment: Yes, these pixels do not contribute to the model loss function, thus you can safely ignore them (exception made for specific dataset biases, such as: "all the flowers of type X have 50% of the pixels black" --> in this case, your model's predictions may be influenced by the black canvas; but it is difficult to quantify this bias and probably it is very little in this dataset)